# Change/Force CMD properties like Window size & Screen Buffer size via GPO, or other ways

Tags: group-policy, windows-command-prompt, vbscript

Is it possible to control CMD properties like Window size & Screen Buffer size via GPO? (or a VBS script that can be pushed using GPO :)

I have Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008.

Many thanks for your advice.

Toast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options are all stored in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

You will most likely have a sub-key called "Command Prompt" that you want to store your information in. You should be able to script it from there.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978570.aspx) is a reference to what all the values mean. It is for Windows 2000, but this section still applies to Win7/2008.

Comment: Thanks MattB.
Did it with this command:
reg add "HKCU\Console" /v "ScreenBufferSize" /t REG_DWORD /d 655304463 /f

Answer (score 1):

I have written a tiny [application](http://www.tenox.net/out/#cmdmax) for Windows that allows to "maximize" the window and buffer. It could be easily extended to allow passing parameters with custom values.